# Find all possible permutations of given array and its subarrays

Tags: javascript

I'm sure this has been answered somewhere, but I can't find an answer for this specific problem with JS before ES5.
I need a function like this:

```
function testAllPossibilities(array, callback) {
    // example array = [Obj1,Obj2];
    // allPossibilites = [
    //   [Obj1],
    //   [Obj2],
    //   [Obj1,Obj2],
    //   [Obj2,Obj1]
    // ]
    for (var i = 0; i < allPossibilites.length; i++) {
        callback(allPossibilites[i]);
    }
}
```

I'm looking for all permutations without repetitions for the original input array and its sub-arrays.

Comment: so, if you have an array of `[1,2,3]`, what combinations do you need?

Comment: `[1],[2],[3],[1,2],[2,1],[1,3],[3,1],[2,3],[3,2],[1,2,3],[1,3,2],[2,1,3],[2,3,1],[3,1,2],[3,2,1]`

Comment: Let me get this straight--you want permutations, but you don't want to learn about permutations?

Comment: this has nothing to do with me learning about permutations - I just want a function that can do this - once I see it I will understand it!
And yes, not knowing how to exactly call it is a minus, but I'm sure smart people out there will understand what I'm trying to accomplish :)

Comment: @Cold_Class, are you also interested in repetitions like `11, 22, 33`, `122`, `112`?

Comment: No, no repetitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function combinate (array) {
  const possibilities = new Set();

  function lookup (possible) {
    if possible.length {
      possibilities.add(possible);
    }

    const p = new Set(possible);
    const further = array.filter(el => !p.has(el));

    for (let entry of further) {
      lookup(possible.concat(entry));
    }
  }

  lookup([]);

  return Array.from(possibilities);
}
```

Do not run this with more than 8 elements.

Comment: Thanks, it gave me the results I was looking for so far!!
I will study your code later to see how you exactly did it - I never used `Set` and `let` before, I will definitely learn a lot from your solution! :)